# Instance declarations of uncommon typeclasses in extra module

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Is it good style to put the instance declarations for uncommon typeclasses in extra modules?

As an example I have this simple tree type:

```
module Data.Tree where

data Tree a = Leaf a
            | Node (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Suppose I want to use QuickCheck's `Arbitrary` typeclass to generate random values of type `Tree` (and be able to use them not only in tests).

What is best? To put them in the same module where `Tree` is defined

```
module Data.Tree where

import QuickCheck.Arbitrary

data Tree a = ...

instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Tree a) where
    ...
```

or to outsource the instance declaration to another module to avoid the dependency to `QuickCheck.Arbitrary` in `Data.Tree`

```
module Data.Tree.Arbitrary where

import Data.Tree
import QuickCheck.Arbitrary

instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (Tree a) where
    ...
```

or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to avoid orphan instances: those are always good for surprises, and rather hard to find.

So, yes, put the instance in the module where `Tree` is defined. This blows up the module a bit, but it shouldn't really be an issue. Of the total build time of the whole package it shouldn't matter much if you have one larger module or two smaller ones.

When you can completely avoid a package dependency, this might make an orphan instance worthwhile, because installing a package is obviously a much greater performance issue than importing a module from an installed package.

Comment: Avoiding package dependencies isn't just a performance issue, it's about avoiding conflicts with other packages which might have dependencies on different version of the library.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: sure, but in case of dependency conflicts an orphan-instance module probably won't help either.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It may help if that module isn't exposed -- e.g. if it is used only internally in a test suite, which looks likely considering the explicit discussion of quickcheck in the question.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It can also help because you can not include the orphan instance module and just define the same instance yourself. (Of course, this only works if 1) you have an application, not a library, and nobody depends on _your_ package; 2) you don't have any dependencies which themselves use the orphan-instance module.)